# Jmeter Jenkins Plugin : Get the report in email

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, html-email, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

I have configured the Jenkins Jmeter plugin and i am able to view the reports as shown in the image. What i need is a way to send these reports as an email content . I am using email-ext plugin for sending mail.

The Jmeter gives me an output of type xml .

What I understand is that jMeter comes with some XSL files which can be used to transform the xml to html (jmeter-results-detail-report.xsl in extras folder). Is there any way to invoke the XSLT transformation directly inside the DefaultContent in email_ext plugin ?
Any Groovy script or something ?

[image: Report]

This is how my configuration looks like :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) which has target to transform JMeter XML result file into HTML format. See /extras/build.xml file under root of your JMeter installation folder

```
<target name="xslt-report" depends="_message_xalan">
  <tstamp><format property="report.datestamp" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"/></tstamp>
  <xslt
      classpathref="xslt.classpath"
      force="true"
      in="${testpath}/${test}.jtl"
      out="${testpath}/${test}.html"
      style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report${style_version}.xsl">
      <param name="showData" expression="${show-data}"/>
      <param name="titleReport" expression="${report.title}"/>
      <param name="dateReport" expression="${report.datestamp}"/>
  </xslt>
</target>
```

See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for more details.